# Program without mpi instrucions is extremely slow in mpirun

Tags: c++, g++, mpi, sunos

I'm writing now a program to study MPI. Okay, I'd write a program that multiplies square matrices.

```c++
long **multiplyMatrices(long **matrix1, long **matrix2, long capacity)
{
    long **resultMatrix = new long*[capacity];

    for (long i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
        resultMatrix[i] = new long[capacity];
    }

    for (long i = 0, j, k; i < capacity; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < capacity; ++j) {
            resultMatrix[i][j] = 0;

            for (k = 0; k < capacity; ++k) {
                resultMatrix[i][j] = resultMatrix[i][j] + matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return resultMatrix;
}
```

Where `capacity == 1000`.

Okay, on localhost (Mac Mini 2012, Core i7, OS X 10.8.2) I compile this code in XCode with LLVM. Calculation takes 17 seconds. Yes, in one thread.

On remote host (Sun OS 5.11, dual-core CPU, 8 vCPU) I compile it with

```
g++ -I/usr/openmpi/ompi-1.5/include -I/usr/openmpi/ompi-1.5/include/openmpi -O2 main.cpp -R/opt/mx/lib -R/usr/openmpi/ompi-1.5/lib -L/usr/openmpi/ompi-1.5/lib -lmpi -lopen-rte -lopen-pal -lnsl -lrt -lm -ldl -lsocket -o main
```

or just

```
g++ -O2 main.cpp -o main
```

But... `mpirun main` takes 152 seconds to calculate this... What's wrong? Am I missing something? Is that's about server's CPU's architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main answer is in memory management.

Look at those lines

```c++
long **resultMatrix = new long*[capacity];

for (long i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
    resultMatrix[i] = new long[capacity];
}
```

All lines are located in different places of memory, not as a whole block. We know how physical memory are presented on Mac Mini — 2 pieces of plastic, but on server it may be even different hosts (cluster).

Now we'll try to fix this.

```c++
long **allocateMatrix(long capacity)
{
    // Allocating a vector of pointers to rows
    long **matrix = (long **)malloc(capacity * sizeof(long *));

    // Allocating a matrix as a whole block
    matrix[0] = (long *)malloc(capacity * capacity * sizeof(long));

    // Initializing a vector of pointers with rows of addresses
    long *lineAddress = matrix[0];
    for(long i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = lineAddress;
        lineAddress += capacity;
    }

    return matrix;
}

void deallocateMatrix(long **matrix, long capacity)
{
    free(matrix[0]);
    free(matrix);
}
```

This boosts code running on Mac Mini to 9.8 seconds, on server — to 58 seconds.

But I still don't know where are other time leaks. Maybe I should somehow optimize looping one of matrices.